# How to use CodePipeline to automate deployment of a batch process using AWS batch and ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-processing, aws-codepipeline, amazon-ecr, aws-batch

I have a dockerized python batch process, if I build, package and push it to AWS ECR, how can I automate the deployment using CodePipeline into AWS Batch? Can someone give me a guidance or share any relevant resources? I couldn't find exactly what I am looking for.

Thank you.